# What to do to make the app "qualified on iOS 4"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have not had much time to read through all the documentation for the 1500 more features included in iOS4, so right now I have 2 questions:

- If the app is just a usual utility application, what to do to make it "qualified on iOS 4"?
- If the app uses a timer to refresh all the items on the screen every one minute (requires redrawing of the sub views), what are the changes that have to be done? ( I notice that even though when I quit the application, open it again in a 3GS iPhone, the timer is still generating events).

**Update**

What I want is the technical part of the story, not the description on the appstore, etc...

E.s. Those applications above have to do something with applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillEnterForeground, applicationDidBecomeActive, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that Apple do when testing your app after you submit it via iTunes Connect.

They will test your app on iOS4 and if they decide it works sufficiently, they'll mark it as tested on iOS4.

If, for whatever reason, it doesn't work well on iOS4, they'll reject the app and let you know what was wrong.

Comment: Test your app on OS4. If it works as you intend, then it'll probably be qualified for OS4. There really is no other technical story behind it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a label given automatically by Apple after they test it on iOS4. You may not actually need to do anything extra to get it.